# Extend Avro schema via Java API by adding one field

Tags: avro

I use the Java API for Avro from Scala and wonder if there is an easy programmatical way to add a field to an existing record schema using the Avro GenericRecord / SchemaBuilder API?

Comment: can you share what you have tried so far? I think the question is not completely clear . Do you want to add a new field to an GenericRecord object which is already instanced?

Comment: So what I want to do is some programmatic schema evolution: I have a GenericRecord and can get it's schema via getSchema() and with that I would like to create a new Schema based on that schema and add one more field. What I found so far is only: getting all fields from existing schema and adding them very cumbersome(with default stuff etc). to a new SchemaBuilder and then adding the new field. Just wondered why it is necessary for me to write all this code myself and if I am just missing sth.non obvious e.g. in the SchemaBuilder API

Comment: it would be useful update your question with the code that you have so far and your expectation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no easy way - but I know exactly what you are trying to do.

Here's an example extending an existing schema (eg SchemaBuilder) dynamically.

```
    Schema schema = SchemaBuilder
            .record("schema_base").namespace("com.namespace.test")
            .fields()
            .name("longField").type().longType().noDefault()
            .name("stringField").type().stringType().noDefault()
            .name("booleanField").type().booleanType().noDefault()
            .name("optionalStringColumn").type().optional().stringType()
            .endRecord();



    List<Schema.Field> field_list = schema.getFields();

    ArrayList<Schema.Field> new_list = new ArrayList();

    //create a new "empty" schema
    //public static Schema createRecord(String name, String doc, String namespace, boolean isError) {

    Schema s2 = Schema.createRecord("new_schema", "info", "com.namespace.test", false);

    //add existing fields
    for(Schema.Field f : field_list) {

        //f.schema() here is really type "schema" like long or string, not a link back to a custom schema
        Schema.Field ff = new Schema.Field(f.name(), f.schema(), f.doc(), f.defaultVal());
        new_list.add(ff);
    }

    //this here is just to show how to create an optional string, its a union of null and string types
    ArrayList<Schema> optionalString = new ArrayList<>();
    optionalString.add(Schema.create(Schema.Type.NULL));
    optionalString.add(Schema.create(Schema.Type.STRING));

    //add the new 3 test fields in as optional string types
    //default value here appears arbitrary, when you write the record if its not optional it doesn't //pick up default value

    String[] sArray = {"test", "test2", "test3"};

    for(String s : sArray) {

        Schema.Field f = new Schema.Field( s, Schema.createUnion(optionalString), s, "null");
        new_list.add(f);
    }

    s2.setFields(new_list);
```

You can't just setFields on the existing schema because once they exist, the schema is locked.

Note: be careful with the default value - if there's a type mismatch everything will write out fine, but you won't be able to read the avro file!

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

Alternatively, you can use [SAvro](https://github.com/irajhedayati/savro).

```
libraryDependencies += "ca.dataedu" %% "savro" % "0.3.0"
```

and then

```scala
schema.addField("newField1", SchemaBuilder.builder().stringType())
```

More examples you can find in the README.

**This is same answer but a different format of coding**

@tmx has provided a complete answer. Once a schema is created, everything is locked. The only way is to implement a copy method. Here is a more compact version:

```java
    // Start with a base schema 
    Schema base = ...;
    // Get a copy of base schema's fields.
    // Once a field is used in a schema, it gets a position.
    // We can't recycle a field and it will throw an exception.
    // Hence, we need a fresh field from each field of the old schema
    List<Schema.Field> baseFields = base.getFields().stream()
                .map(field -> new Schema.Field(field.name(), field.schema(), field.doc(), field.defaultVal()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    // Add your field
    baseFields.add(new Schema.Field("Name", newFieldSchema));
    Schema newSchema = Schema.createRecord(
        base.getName(), 
        "New schema by adding a new field", 
        "com.my.name.space", 
        false, 
        baseFields);
```

having `baseFields`, you could do any modification you'd like, add/delete/modify.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't forget to add aliases if you can have them

```
   List<Schema.Field> baseFields = base.getFields().stream()
            .map(field -> {
                Schema.Field f = new Schema.Field(field.name(), field.schema(), field.doc(), field.defaultVal());
                field.aliases().forEach(f::addAlias);
                return f;
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```