# Transform Stream

Tags: java, scala, apache-flink, avro

I have a GenericRecord stream with value deserialised using Avro, schema has name and age.

```
 KafkaSource<GenericRecord> source = KafkaSource.<GenericRecord>builder()
                .setBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
                .setTopics("sucheth1")
                .setGroupId("my-group")
                .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
 .setValueOnlyDeserializer(ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema.forGeneric(schema, "http://localhost:8081"))
                .build();

 DataStream<GenericRecord> stream = env.fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "Kafka Source");
```

I'm trying to map each record and add a new field 'location' to the stream and I get error saying

```
Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Not a valid schema field: location
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record.put(GenericData.java:242)
Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Not a valid schema field: location
```

Is there a way I can transform the stream by adding new fields?

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is Avro, not Flink. Your transformation (the map function) will need to emit records that use a different schema (one that includes the new field).

[Extend Avro schema via Java API by adding one field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47161408/extend-avro-schema-via-java-api-by-adding-one-field) may provide some helpful insight.

Comment: DataStream<GenericRecord> filtered = stream.filter(gen -> gen.get("name").toString().equals("sucheth"));

DataStream<GenericRecord> mapped =  filtered.map(rec -> rec);

Comment: map operation on stream throw my error, 
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to deserialize consumer record due to
 at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.reader.KafkaRecordEmitter.emitRecord(KafkaRecordEmitter.java:54)


Do you know why ?

Comment: @SuchethShivakumar were you able to figure it out? I dont have an additional field and yet still get the same error

Comment: @Nikki I have got past this. it's been long time forgot how.